# Send multiple lines to Arduino from a listbox C#

Tags: c#, listbox

```
int nums = lstbox.SelectedItems.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < nums; i++)
{
    string itemz = (lstbox.SelectedItems[i].ToString());
    serialPort1.Write(itemz);
    Thread.Sleep(50);
```

I want to turn on some LEDS using this method. It doesnt work for more than 1 item with this method, which is the first one. Thread.sleep doesnt work, i was thinking maybe i can pause between tasks. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have the `SelectionMode` property of the 'ListBox` = `MultiExtended`.? Otherwise the `SelectedItems` will always return a single item if any.

Comment: yes, multiple is selected